# AS3 Variables from http query string

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I am writing an air application in which some keystrokes are sent that activate functions.
Now, since this means that the application shall not be iconized (otherwise the shortcuts would not work), I want to understand if it is possible to send commands (variables) using http query strings.
I have an external device that is capable to send the requests for example: http://localhost/?var=1.

I tried opening a socket but it receives 0 length data when I send something.

Any other suggestion is of course welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Use **URLLoader** class, it is intended for HTTP requests: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite understand fully...I don't have any real url, I would like to pass data on the fly with the query string. Do you have any example?

Comment: You can compose the URL as a **String**, or you can also use the dedicated **URLVariables** class (example is at the bottom of the page):https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html